# SkiaSharp on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a .NET core 3.0 API deployed on AWS Lambda. I am using SkiaSharp dll. I get this error:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libSkiaSharp' or one of its dependencies. liblibSkiaSharp: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

I have tried nuget packages of Skiasharp, skiasharp.NativeAssests.Linux, Avalonia.Skiasharp.NativeAsstes.Linux and also tried with Skiasharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies but I'm still getting that error

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux package to your NuGet dependencies. Found that into on this [AWS Form post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=312708).

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I tried with all below packages but couldn't get it to work. I have tried nuget packages of Skiasharp, skiasharp.NativeAssests.Linux, Avalonia.Skiasharp.NativeAsstes.Linux and also tried with Skiasharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies

Comment: I finally got back to looking at this and got it working. What fixed it for me was using the SkiaSharp.NativeAssets.Linux.NoDependencies NuGet package. Found that mention in their GitHub repo, tried it, and magically it worked! If you don't need fonts and such (which we don't) that may do it for you too.